# Was the cliffhanger ending of the animated series Reboot ever resolved in any media?

Tags: reboot-1994

I rewatched the 1990s CGI series *Reboot* for the first time since the '90s. I had forgotten that the final season ended on a unresolved cliffhanger due to low ratings shutting down production!

Was the resolution ever published in any form?  (There is a related live action/animated series on Netflix currently, but from the little I could bear to watch, it does not seem to continue the plot).

Comment: The creator refused to resolve it in 2012; https://youtu.be/FpwGTo7tKGg?t=793 / https://youtu.be/7RAtrVCiDUE?t=273

Comment: Similarly, the writer refused in 2010; https://web.archive.org/web/20150725224357/http://sittingonanatomicbomb.com/2010/09/27/interview-with-reboot-co-creator-gavin-blair/

Comment: Well, that's a bummer!

Comment: Blair also refused to resolve it in 2019 when he was asked on his twitter

Comment: Thanks for the links in any case; I especially enjoyed reading the 2010 one.